# How to check if attribute exist in product attribute set? Magento

Tags: magento, attributes, product, catalog

How to check if attribute exist in product attribute set?

I need to know if a product has an attribute for its set of attributes.

I get the attribute with:

```
$attrPricekg = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId())->getPricekg();
```

If attribut exist in product attribute set, $attrPricekg display: set value for the product
or 0 if no value set for the product.

If the attribute does not exist in product attribute set, $attrPricekg display 0. This is my problem.. I need to avoid this, I want to check that the attribute does not exist for that product.

Thanks.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

***EDIT: this is not the correct answer.***

```
$product->offsetExists('pricekg');
```

See [`Varien_Object::offsetExists()` (link)](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/lib/Varien/Object.php#L850).

Comment: Will this only return true if there is a value for that attribute? Or does magento put in a key in $_data with a NULL value when there is no record in the product_entity_attribute_[type] tables?

Comment: Someone, please DELETE this answer!

Comment: @HenryHayes ok :-) 

ETA shit, not sure why this is marked as the answer.

Answer (score 28):

now I'll provide an answer which works regardless!

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(16);

$eavConfig = Mage::getModel('eav/config');
/* @var $eavConfig Mage_Eav_Model_Config */

$attributes = $eavConfig->getEntityAttributeCodes(
    Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY,
    $product
);

if (in_array('pricekg',$attributes)) {
    // your logic
}
```

Answer (score 6):

To check if a specific attribute exists in product, it should return true even if the attribute has the value 'null'.

One way that works is:

```
$attr = Mage::getModel('catalog/resource_eav_attribute')->loadByCode('catalog_product',$code);
if (null!==$attr->getId())
```

{
        //attribute exists code here
    }

It can also of course be written in one line:

```
if(null!===Mage::getModel('catalog/resource_eav_attribute')->loadByCode('catalog_product','attributecode_to_look_for')->getId()) {
    //'attributecode_to_look_for' exists code here
}
```

Found it and modified a bit on:
https://github.com/astorm/Pulsestorm/issues/3

Comment: this one is general and overall perfect. i needed that to remove an attribute only if it exists. to remove existing attrib `$installer->removeAttribute('catalog_product', 'attributecode_to_look_for');` simple.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. After adding a closing bracket to the condition of the first example it works!

Answer (score 0):

May be this way is better for you:

```
$attribute = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId)->getResource()->getAttribute($attributeCode);
if ($attribute && $attribute->getId()) { ... }
```

Also you may try

```
$attributes = $product->getAttributes();
```

But you may check all in attribute collection:

```
$entityTypeId = Mage::getModel('eav/entity')
            ->setType('catalog_product')
            ->getTypeId();
$attributeId = 5;
$attributeSetName   = 'Default';
$attributeSetId     = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')
                ->getCollection()
                ->addFieldToFilter('entity_type_id', $entityTypeId)
                ->addFieldToFilter('attribute_set_name', $attributeSetName)
                ->addFieldToFilter('attribute_id', $attributeId)
                ->getFirstItem();
```

May be source code need some corrections, but I think you will understand the idea.

See some more examples here, also - http://www.blog.magepsycho.com/playing-with-attribute-set-in-magento/

Comment: The first solution doesn't  work correctly. I need to check for specific product.

Comment: Try to do $attribute = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(1)->getResource()->getAttribute($attributeCode);

Comment: also you may try
$attributes = $product->getAttributes();

Comment: Thanks. :)  $attributes = $product->getAttributes() and foreach construct helped me!!!